# Could someone please tell the difference between "turns out that" & "turns out to be"

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I'm confused between these two phrasal verbs. I'm going to quote here two examples but since I'm learning so I might be wrong, do correct me here. "It turns out that it was a conspiracy against him" and "it turns out to be a conspiracy against him".